# Angular 2 authentication from database

Tags: angular, authentication

I would like to ask to about authentication method in angular. I would like to create simply app with login and registration. I will create for it standard database. May you please advise me how I can do it in angular2? Is there any friendly library for that or should I use something else to communicate with database?

Comment: Angular is a client-side framework, authentication and database communications are server-side aspect. Angular can communicate with your backend which will handle the authentication

Answer (score 0):

Angular , react , Angular 2 , vue all these frameworks are client-side framework it is not possible to achieve it with just that . However you can use a serverside language along with angular to do it . you can easily achieve the above with Nodejs or java . Also you will find many resources online to do the above using firebase you can give a look to that as well.

Comment: I knew that with client-side framework it is not possible. Probably I wrongly wrote my question. But I would like to ask how to do it with nodeJS? I tried to find some tutorial or valuable documentation, but it was hard to get something helpful. May you please provide me more details or point me where to search?

Comment: @agims7 you can find several tutorials on youtube over it using nodejs and firebase. We cant help you unless you put some effort into it.

Comment: Ok I will use MEAN